# Pipe between current process and other process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to make pipe or queue in Python between one process (current) and other existing in system. how can I make it? I know current and other process ID.
I work on Windows 32bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this.

```
python one_process.py | python the_other_process.py
```

Make the OS do the work for you.

In `one_process.py`, you write to `sys.stdout`.

In `the_other_process.py`, you read from `sys.stdin`.

That's it.